# How to connect to sql server database from android device

Tags: android, sql-server, jdbc, ip

I want to build android app that can connect to sql server database using jtds jdbc. When i try run the program at emulator with ip 10.0.2.2, it works fine. But when i try build apk and install it to android device,i change the ip to 192.168.0.5 (my computer ip in LAN) and it doesnt work, Please help.

[here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtZ3m.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your phone is also on the same network to which your computer is connected.

It is not a good idea to expose database directly to the client. instead you can have a web service in your computer which does database operations and you can call the web service from your android app.

Comment: Yes my phone is on the same wifi network as my computer, but it still cant connect to it, can u help me? I know that its better to connect android to database via web server thing, but i dont understand how web server for android works, do i have to install the web server in all android device that use the program, or just install it in the server computer? and what web server can i use for this? Thankyou

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/ is this a good solution?